# Mac Cocoa App - Objective-C - Different Main menu in different NSViewController

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, menu, nsviewcontroller

I have a Main menu set in my Application. It has App, Edit, View and Window menus. That is what I need in the main NSViewController.

However there is another NSViewController which the user can open, and I would like to add some menu items to Edit menu, while this NSViewController is active.

What is the standard was of achieving this?

Comment: Put all menu items in the main menu and disable or hide the menu items you don't want.

Comment: I tried that, but the window I open is modal and it doesn't execute the proper actions.

Comment: From a user-experience (UX) standpoint, it's generally a bad idea to have features that hide and show in ways that aren't *immediately* obvious to the user.  My advice is to have all menu items in the menu at all times and just disable the ones you don't need for a particular usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NSMenuDelegate method such as

```
- (void)menuNeedsUpdate:(NSMenu*)menu;
```

And inside this method you can Add/Remove or Enable/Disable the specific item based on specific conditions.